# PHPMailer Can't send E-Mails to gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I couldn't send mails to gmail accounts. Sending mails to other providers works. The mail also does not end up in the spam folder and there is no response to the sender address. I also register the domains f in the Google Postmaster Tool to verify the Domain.
Could the problem be that the script is running on a different server than the email domain? On this case, the script is just running on my local machine for development.

When I send Mails from the E-Mail Servers Webinterface, it works.

This is the header when I send the Email to GMX:

```
Return-Path: <info@rescueoffice.de>
Authentication-Results: gmx.net; dkim=none
Received: from dd38416.kasserver.com ([85.13.128.172]) by mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmx101 [212.227.17.5]) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 1MmlP4-1pF3po3RYM-00joqF for <julia_reeh@gmx.de>; Thu, 08 Sep 2022 23:50:14 +0200
Received: from localhost (unknown [85.233.52.241]) by dd38416.kasserver.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 33A4F44405D5 for <julia_reeh@gmx.de>; Thu, 8 Sep 2022 23:50:14 +0200 (CEST)
Date: Thu, 8 Sep 2022 21:50:13 +0000
To: Markus Bodmann <julia_reeh@gmx.de>
From: Intranet Rettungsdienst LK Harburg <info@rescueoffice.de>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Logindaten_f=C3=BCr_Markus_Bodmann?=
Message-ID: <uUg4R9CgLINIj7xxWDaGHDxutEMuF1YIKKrJ0@localhost>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Envelope-To: <julia_reeh@gmx.de>
X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam); Detail=V3;
X-Spam-Flag: NO
```

**EDIT**

```
function sendMail(string $from, string $to, string $toName, string $subject, string $body): bool
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host         = MAIL_HOST;
        $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
        $mail->Username     = MAIL_USER;
        $mail->Password     = MAIL_PASSWORD;
        $mail->SMTPSecure   = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
        $mail->Port         = MAIL_PORT;

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom(MAIL_SENDER, $from);
        $mail->addAddress($to, $toName);

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body;

        $mail->send();

        return true;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't tell form what you've posted. You need to show your code and tell us how mail is routed from your script to gmail (e.g. what's your `Host` property set to?). If you're using a local mail server, details of onward deliveries will be in its logs, not in PHPMailer output.

Comment: @Synchro I added my function above. Just a little Mail Script. The Script is running local for developing. The Mailserver is a Mail Server from a hosting package. When I send E-Mais from the Mail Server Webinterface to Gmail there are no Problems.

Comment: What is `MAIL_HOST` set to? If it's `localhost`, what is in your mail server's logs?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that jumps out at me is that **Reply-To** is missing.

You may already have looked at it.  But for completeness, you should look at this document [Prevent emails to Gmail users from being blocked or sent to spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en-GB)

There are various sites that will check your email for spam score.  You should try them.  I tried the headers you have on one of them.  The results are not fully valid as I didn't have the full email.  But it did not like the **Date** header.  I found a few years ago that **bigpond** was very fussy about the date header.  Another ISP wanted the **User-Agent** header.

Comment: If the address where you want replies to go is the same as your from address, you don't need a reply-to; it would achieve nothing.

Comment: @Synchro - You are correct that the standard does not require it.  However, the issue about why ISP's may block or mark your email as spam has nothing to do with what field is optional on the specification.

Comment: @Synchro - The same applies to **Message-Id** field - it too is optional  ref https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt.  But try sending emails without it

Comment: I've sent over 200 million emails without reply-to. It doesn't cause spam filter issues, in fact I'd expect picky filters to flag duplicate values if it was used unnecessarily. PHPMailer ignores reply-to if it's the same as the from address. Date is a required field, one of only two. Message-ID is indeed really necessary, as it's difficult to run an email service without it, and it would break threading. User-agent is very bizarre thing to require as it's not mentioned at all in specs, is really a web thing. Most MUAs use `X-Mailer` to identify themselves, if they bother at all.